# My Peace Lily is droopy but, it's still growing new leaves that are upright?

Tags: peace-lily

I have tried EVERYTHING to get this peace lily to revive and nothing seems to perk up the leaves. However, the new growth (at present it has given me 6 new leaves in the space of two weeks) are healthy and upright as normal.

I cannot figure out what is wrong/what to do!

Comment: Please upload a photo of the plant and share your location roughly.